# Reaching Ionic specific page from URL

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to reach a specific page in an Ionic3 app , from an external source , like another website , or a python script.

I would like to know if I can transfer data to the app, but without having the app asking for the data

Comment: I'm confused, so you're asking if you can grab data from like an API? or actually navigate to another external link inside the app?

Comment: i want to know if from another external website i can navigate to  a specific page in my ionic web app ,  reaching direclty a login page for exemple . and if so , if i can load data into this page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

such functionality is typically called “deep links” for apps. Its not easy to build such experience with apps due to platform differences (ios vs android). There are solutions that abstract differences and provide good overall implementation path: branch.io.

Branch features [native plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/branchio/) for Ionic 3+.

You can google guides for actual implementation.

Comment: indeed , deep links seems to be what i was looking for , thanks for this enlightenment.